# OSError in Python?

Tags: python

first time on here.

I'm currently hitting a snafu with an assignment.

I'm writing a function to check for annotations but I'm getting an issue with when I'm comparing values.

So for ex. I'm using

```
    def check_type():
        try:
            if isinstance(value, annot):
                pass
            else:
                raise AssertionError(str(param) + ' failed annotation check(wrong type): value = '+
                                         str(value)+ ' was type ' + str(type(value).__name__)+ 
                                         ' ...should be type '+ str(annot.__name__)) 
        except:
            print('well')
            raise AssertionError(str(param) + ' failed annotation check(wrong type): value = '+
                                    str(value)+ ' was type ' + str(type(value).__name__)+ 
                                     ' ...should be type '+ str(annot.__name__))
```

Currently, if isinstance(value,annot) yields True, everything works correctly.
However, if not: I get a nasty OSError.
It doesn't go to the else block, it just gives me OSError.

Even with the try/except block, it doesn't process correctly. It will go to it and print "well" but it will not raise the AssertionError. It does everything except the raise AssertionError and gives me an OSError anyways.

I'm thinking that there is some issue with raising an AssertionError but when I try to print out the message manually, it works. It's just when I try to raise the AssertionError that I continuously get the OSError.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: What is `x` and what is `y`?

Comment: What exactly is the stacktrace? What line is `OSError` raised on? And what is the exception message and errno? Also, what is the type of Error exactly?

Comment: x is str.
as in variable1 = 'str' and x = type(variable1)
y is an object.

So when y is a string, it passes correctly.

When y is not a string, I get a nasty OSError.

Error message had something about not being able to get source code.

Comment: Your code and the description of your issue don't seem to match up at all. Can you edit to clarify, and perhaps include the full traceback of the exception you're getting?

Comment: Try raising an empty AssertionError. It could be something to do with the formatting/access of the variables when constructing the exception

Comment: Hey, you're right. Holy smokes, that was really really insightful, turns out the issue was elsewhere when I was using this in other functions. I did that part incorrectly so this part was incorrect. When I fixed the other part, this part came together. Thank you so much to everyone for their input!